# How to get an HTML codes when you make a website in Figma?

Tags: html, configmap, figma

Do anyone know how to get the html & CSS when you make websites in Figma? like the actual html codes

I tried following a tutorial in Youtube but it did not work. I want to convert my web designs into html codes so I could use it in Visual Studios

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Figma is a mockup tool, even if it *could* generate the code it would turn out very badly, not responsive... since the web uses very different layout systems (the box model, flexbox, grid etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get code from Figma.

Figma is a design and mockup tool - like Adobe XD and Sketch, not a web design app like Adobe Dreamweaver or WordPress.